# Enforcing factory pattern to a specific set of types by replacing their constructor

Tags: c#, interceptor, factory-pattern, il

It it possible, in ANY way (IL hacks included) to **automatically** "replace" the call to a certain constructor, eg

```
public void Car(Color color)
{
    this.Color = color;
}
```

By a factory method, eg

```
public static Car Create(Color color)
{
    return new Car(color);
}
```

that returns the original type of a subtype of it?

I would like to archive automatic factories through an interface: Get all Types and replace or at least work around their constructor.

Any thoughts on intercepting and IL hacking are welcome. I tried to add an extension method to all types that implement the interface, but as you know static methods are not working out.

Comment: Couldn't you just change the constructor to be `private` and then go through all your compile errors?

Comment: I would like to archive not to edit through hundrets of classes and thousands of their usages plus give the easy possibility to other users to do the same.

Comment: Why is this not a case of finding & replacing `= new Car(` with `= CarFactory.Create(`? (I use `CarFactory` to distinguish from the original class).

Comment: Because I don't want to touch the classes (except adding an interface) and all the constructor calls. Otherwise I would already have replaced everything. Plus the side-goal is (as stated above) to give other people the possbility to avoid the replacement. So the answer of SKleanthous already goes in the right direction by not just replacing everything in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task, but if you have to, you can do this with IL Weaving. I have done a similar thing in the past in a test project, while trying to implement a checked exception library. I did not get around to finishing this due to time constraints.

If you do own the library, then indeed marking the ctor as private will be enough :) but I am guessing that in order to ask, you already exhausted that possibility. Due to this I assume that compile time solutions are not enough. If they are OK, but still you do not want to mark your ctor as private, then check [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) I DEFINITELLY recommend it!

Otherwise, you can use [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). With Cecil you will be able to load a library, load types, find methods, and scan for calls to the Car ctor and replace them with a call of your own. This will be a task that will require quite a bit of IL knowledge and is quite involved for a StackOverflow answer.

If you are launching the application from assembly A and:

- Car is defined in assembly B and all types required are either in B or referenced by B: unload B, weave your changes in B (in a temporary copy if you do not want to change the original), reload B.
- Car is defined in assembly B but types required are not in B or A: Same as above, but you during your weave you will have to add references to the assemblies that the required types are in.
- Car is in A or you need to reference types in A in the factory method: You need to weave the caller assemblies (the assemblies calling the Car ctor).
- Car is in A and the caller is from A: You can copy the assembly, weave the assembly, close and relaunch from the weaved assembly. Instead of this scenario consider using [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would definatly preferr using some kind of IL modification but I'd like to do that on the fly, without modifying the compiled assembly itself. The goal is to load all types with a specific interface and replace all constructor-calls with a call to a factory method - any ideas on that approach?

Comment: You can do this on the fly. It is possible to copy the assemblies to a temp folder, unload the loaded assemblies, change the copied assemblies and load them. This is definitely not standard procedure.

Comment: @SKleanthous what if the type is not in another assembly?

Comment: @SlapY I have updated my answer. Please see it and if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: @Skleanthous I have not yet evaluated the solution but I will. As soon as I'm finished, I'll mark this as answer (if it works ;-) )